# Extracting value dynamically from key==value set from a Decoded URL String, given a key

Tags: java, string, url

I have a Decoded URL String that is created dynamically that is in the following form.

```
field1==Z;field2==abc;field3==000;field4==100000154;field5==XLPO;field6==Z3&limit=2
```

I want to be able to dynamically pass in a key and obtain its relavent value. Say if we pass in "field2" then we should get "abc".

Example:

```
 public class ComplexQueryParamProcessor {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String URL = "field1==Z;field2==abc;field3==000;field4==100000154;field5==XLPO;field6==Z3&limit=2";
        String value = getValueFromURLString(URL, "field4"); // should return "100000154"
        System.out.println(value);
    }


    public static String getValueFromURLString (String URL, String key){
        String value = null;
        //do something and extract "value" of "key" from URL
        
        return value;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try to do something on your own before we help you. Hint: Take a look at the indexOf and substring methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [schred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11213660/schred) I was able to figure it out using a combination of indexOf() and split()

```
 public static String getValueFromURLString (String URL, String key){
        String value = null;
        //do something and extract "value" of "key" from URL
        int index =  URL.indexOf(key);
        String s1 = URL.substring(index, URL.length());
        String s2 = s1.split(";" , 2)[0];
        value = s2.split("==", 2)[1];

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Good job rajeevbk!